# how use ToFileTime in C# in android?

Tags: java, c#, android, .net, kotlin

can I use [ToFileTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tofiletime?view=netframework-4.8) for date-time in C# for Java(Android) project?
my project connects to a server and the server gets time from me by ToFileTime format.

in C#

```
  DateTime testdate1 = new DateTime(2000, 10, 11);
  Console.WriteLine(testdate1.ToFileTime());

  show -> 126156834000000000
```

Comment: What have you tried? What is happening or not happening? What is your code?

Comment: @Christopher edit my Q

Comment: `can I use` What happened when you tried?

Comment: I need time in java on base 1961

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally a DateTime stores the [Ticks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks) that happened since the begin of the UnixEpoch. Every other property and the string output are just an interpretation of that value.

"126156834000000000" looks very much like a tick value (as DateTime retreival lacks the precision to fill in those later digits). And [ToFileTime()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tofiletime) does indeed return the tick value.

Maybe you wanted the result of `testdate1.ToString()`? But even that might be a bad idea.

I got 3 rules for working with Numbers and in particular Datetime:

1. Always Store, Retreive and Transmit the UTC value. And hope you do not have to deal with Timezones manually in your application
2. Never Store, Retreive or Transmit them as String. String is terrible for processing. The only thing worse is Binary.
3. If you can not follow Rule 2, make sure you pick a fixed String Enconding and Culture to be used at all Endpoints. Stuff like XML & JSON take care of that for you.

Comment: @RasoulMiri: I have not used Serialisation that much, but you should use XML or JSON. JSON has a ton less overhead, but XML is more human readable | As for the value to transmit: The more I look at it, the better ToFileTimeUTC() looks. It returns a INT64, a primitive type. If XML or JSON could not reliably transmit that, you could not trust it with anything. And we do trust it with a lot more. My only worry is that counting the ticks might be too .NET specific. That it is not supported by any other language.